# Debugging FaceBook Connect with Local IIS / Visual Studio

Tags: .net, debugging, facebook

Does anyone know how to setup a development environment so I can debug FaceBook connect in ASP.NET?

I have my code working and running fine on the live site. However, in order to test anything I need to write my code, deploy and see where it goes wrong on the live/test site. Not ideal by any stretch of the imagination :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I registered the URL http://localhost/ and got an API key from Facebook.. I can now debug in my development environment.